# quarkus: hibernate entityManger with inject

Tags: quarkus

According to [Quarkus Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm), we can inject a thread safe entityManger by @Inject.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SantaClausService {
    @Inject
    EntityManager em; 

    @Transactional 
    public void createGift(String giftDescription) {
        Gift gift = new Gift();
        gift.setName(giftDescription);
        em.persist(gift);
    }
}
```

However, when I do so, the warning:

```
No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point
```

comes.

When trying to compile, I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException:
Unsatisfied dependency for type javax.persistence.EntityManager 
and qualifiers [@Default]
```

This means, I **must** qualify the injected entityManger by an annotation which I must create and assign to that entityManager. This would not be needed in jee with `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em`.

Is there any prepared entityManager in Quarkus which is already qualified and ready to use without warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your `Gift` a `@Entity` annotation?

This error is a bit misleading. 
If you have no `@Entity` class you will get this error, too.

I tried it... without `@Entity` get the error, then i add `@Entity` to class everything works fine.